# Unexpected results using has_one association for lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-one

I have a has_one association for a location on a company entity:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :country, :postal_code, :state
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :headquarters, :class_name => "Location"
end
```

The underlying schema for the company entity contains a location_id attribute. I expect I should be able to access a company's headquarters location info like so:

```
Company.find(12345).headquarters
```

However, this results in an exception:

```
SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."company_id" = 12345 LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column locations.company_id does not exist
```

I am confused as to why this is behaving this way. I expect the FK to be in companies, not locations (i.e. SELECT * FROM location WHERE locations.id = 12345). I have other lookups defined this same way and they behave as I expect.

A few things to note:

- A location does not belong to a company, many entity types can have a
  location
- I have tried being more/less verbose in my association definition,
  seems to make no difference
- I also at one point tried 'has_one :location' to keep things simple,
  same result

Any help is appreciated.

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using belongs_to rather than has_one.  Specifically,

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :headquarters, :class_name => "Location", :foreign_key => "location_id"
end
```

because you're saying that the foreign key is on the Company rather than the Location.

Answer (score 0):

When you say, a Company has_one location, you imply that it's upto the Locations table to have the FK.  A `has_one` relationship is a one-to-one relationship and in your case it makes perfect sense to add a `company_id` to the `Locations` table.

A `belongs_to` relationship (i.e. Location belongs_to Company) won't make sense here, because that will allow you to link multiple companies to one location.  Unless, of course, you want to allow that, lose the `has_one` relationship on the `Company` model and add a `belongs_to` relationship on the `Location` model instead.

**Update**

`company has_many_and_belongs_to location` would be a better choice of relationship, given that a company can have many locations and one location can have many companies.

I would just add an extra column in the locations table (is_headquarter) to identify a company's headquarter.

Comment: Company A, Company B and Company C can all have their headquarters in same city, so linking is good.

Comment: yep, that's what I said :)

Comment: Wait, are you saying that the belongs_to should be in company or in location for the linking to work?

Comment: location belongs_to company. rather a more apt relationship will be company has_many_and_belongs_to location.  a company can have many locations and one location can have many companies. it's more of a many-to-many relationship and it won't be enough to link these two with a one-to-one relationship (belongs_to).